# Persisting sensitve data in asp.net, odd implementation

Tags: asp.net, security, caching, variables, persistence

For reasons not in scope of this question I have implemented a .net project in an iframe which runs from a classic asp page.  The classic asp site persisted a few sensitive values by hitting the db on each page.

I have passed there variables as xml to the aspx page, now I need to make these values available on any page of this .net site.

I've looked into the cache object but we are on a web farm so I am not sure it would work.
Is there a way I can can instantiate an object in a base page class and have other pages inherit from the base page to access these values?

What is the best way to persist these values?

A few more points to consider the site runs in https mode and I cannot use session variables, and I would like to avoid cookies if possible..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've misunderstood but, if the ASP classic pages were just hitting the db why didn't you just have the ASP.Net pages do the same? That would certainly solve the web-farm issue and is probably why the ASP classic pages work that way to begin with.

Comment: I would like to avoid a hit the db on each page request to set these flags, I could employ the same method and use the cache object but as I understand it, the web farm and caching wil not work unless I use a naming convention tying the session ID to the value.  Thanks for your suggestion and I am have to go that way to make sure the data is not stale.